# Ephesians 5:22-33 husband should have a Passionate Love for his wife But 1 Corinthians 7:29 says husband(& wives) should Not idolize(worship) marriage

Tags: jesus, marriage, love, idolatry, worship

> Ephesians 5:22-33
>
> Marriage Like Christ and the Church
>
> 22 Wives, be subject to your own husbands, as to the Lord. 23 For the
> husband is the head of the wife, as Christ also is the head of the
> church, He Himself being the Savior of the body. 24 But as the church
> is subject to Christ, so also the wives ought to be to their husbands
> in everything.
>
> **25 Husbands, love your wives, just as Christ also loved the church and gave Himself up for her,** 26 so that He might sanctify her,
> having cleansed her by the washing of water with the word, 27 that He
> might present to Himself the church [a]in all her glory, having no
> spot or wrinkle or any such thing; but that she would be holy and
> blameless. 28 So husbands ought also to love their own wives as their
> own bodies. He who loves his own wife loves himself; 29 for no one
> ever hated his own flesh, but nourishes and cherishes it, just as
> Christ also does the church, 30 because we are members of His body. 31
> For this reason a man shall leave his father and mother and shall be
> joined to his wife, and the two shall become one flesh. 32 This
> mystery is great; but I am speaking with reference to Christ and the
> church. 33 Nevertheless, each individual among you also is to love his
> own wife even as himself, and the wife must see to it that she
> [b]respects her husband.

Ephesians 5:25 say that husbands should Love their wives which all reflects how
Jesus Christ Loves The Church, and also how Jesus Christ gave Himself up which suggest/hints crucifying Himself on the cross in order to die for the church.
Therefore, based on Ephesians 5:25 , the bible reader can infer/deduce that Jesus Christ has an extremely Passionate Love for The Christian Church.  Furthermore, Ephesians 5:22-33 emphasizes that a husband's relationship with his wife should reflect Jesus Christ's relationship with The Christian Church.  **Therefore, we could further infer/deduce that a husband also has to have an extremely Passionate Love for his wife.**

> ( 1 Corinthians 7:25-31 )
>
> 25 Now concerning virgins I have no command of the Lord, but I give an
> opinion as one who [a]by the mercy of the Lord is trustworthy. 26 I
> think then that this is good in view of the [b]present distress, that
> it is good for a man [c]to remain as he is.27 Are you bound to a wife?
> Do not seek to be released. Are you released from a wife? Do not seek
> a wife. 28 But if you marry, you have not sinned; and if a virgin
> marries, she has not sinned. Yet such will have trouble in this life,
> and I am trying to spare you. **29 But this I say, brethren, the time
> has been shortened, so that from now on those who have wives should be
> as though they had none;** 30 and those who weep, as though they did
> not weep; and those who rejoice, as though they did not rejoice; and
> those who buy, as though they did not possess; 31 and those who use
> the world, as though they did not make full use of it; for the form of
> this world is passing away.

However, 1 Corinthians 7:29 seems to suggest that husband(and their wives) should Not idolize(and/or worship) their marriage.

How should we view

Ephesians 5:22-33(specifically Ephesians 5:25) which suggests that a husband should have an extremely Passionate Love for his wife

in light of

1 Corinthians 7:29 bible verse which says husband(and their wives) should Not idolize(and/or worship) their marriage?

Other Related Question postings:  [Literary devices explaining Paul's use of language style when it comes to marrying or even being involved in worldliness (1 Corinthians 7:27-31)?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/56907/literary-devices-explaining-pauls-use-of-language-style-when-it-comes-to-marryi)

Comment: There is no suggestion that Christ 'idolizes' the Church : he loves it. Then why would husbands ever want to idolize their wives ?  : they love them.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the two passages, 1 Cor 7:25-31 and Eph 5:25-28 is discussing passion - the word in the Greek for such passionate "love" is "eros" which is not mentioned.

What IS mentioned is agape love - the kind of love which Paul describes as Christ having for the church.  Indeed, the agape love is according to Eph 5:25 -

> Husbands, love [ ἀγαπάω ] your wives, just as Christ loved the church and gave
> Himself up for her

THAT - is extremely demanding, selfless love at a very high standard.  Such a love is NOT based on passion but upon principle.  This is not to suggest that sexual passion is absent - far from it, but that is not the primary motivation and basis for a Christian marriage.

Paul, in 1 Cor 7:1-6 makes it clear that in a normal healthy marriage, sexual expression has an integral part.  Later in the same chapter Paul essentially says two more things:

- being single is acceptable and often a desirable state of affairs where practical
- being married is not wrong and is better for some people.

Back to Eph 5 - Paul is very clear that "agape" love is to be the basis of marriage and NOT passion.  Agape love is other-focused, selfless, considerate, kind and courteous - see 1 Cor 13 for a longer definition of this kind of love.